# Which is efficient, itoa or sprintf?

Tags: c++

I am in the processes of building my first C++ application and choosing an efficient C++ libraries to rely on at this stage, is one of the design consideration I am looking at.

Consequently I want to convert an integer type to string and deciding on whether to use;

```
sprintf(string, "%d", x);
```

Or

**Integer to ASCI**

```
itoa(x, string);
```

Can anyone suggest which one of these route is efficient and possibly why?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `istringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast`? It's C++ after all.

Comment: Will integer formatting really be the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Every little count at this stage.

Comment: @Bitmap: Really, at the early design stage? When you most likely will burn thousands of cycles later on that mutex contention and bad cache locality? Oh well, go ahead... best to make a simple test program and compare the assembly, I suppose.

Comment: @Bitmap : The problem is, different solutions have different levels of complexity. E.g., Boost.Spirit outperforms the solutions presented here, but has quiet a learning curve for someone new to C++... So sticking with the standard library is probably best for someone new to the language, regardless of performance.

Comment: `my first C++ application` : what makes you think that every little count is important?  It is not, finishing it is the only thing that's important right now.  Unless you don't actually want to, that's not uncommon.

Comment: @Bitmap: If you are at the "design" stage, I highly doubt that "every little counts".

Comment: As you would agree prove of concepts most at times becomes the actual solution, I am developing as I go on and need to be aware of the right choices as I move on. I know not bothering too much about integer conversion will still yield efficiency yet need to understand their impact, to establish whether i do even need them.

Comment: Never use `sprintf`. **Ever**. If `stringstream` is not to your taste, then use `snprintf`. So many buffer overrun attacks could be prevented if people used this. Same goes for `itoa`, but that isn't even standard C or C++.

Comment: Of the two you mention itoa is not even standard and both itoa and sprintf are dangerous. But your question is just wrong, worrying about this kind of efficiency will just hold you back. Think about real programming issues, ones that actually matter. Like how to write bug free, understandable code. This kind of efficiency concern will make the difference of a few milliseconds at most and will be **unnoticeable** by the users of your programs. I really don't understand where the newbie concern about efficiency comes from, don't you realise that computers are fast?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas `snprintf()` trades one large set of problems of `sprintf()` for another (smaller yet significant).  A terse "never use" without explaining how to properly use `snprintf()` in itself sets up for other problems.  `snprintf(command, 12, "format disk not");` is a problem too.

Comment: @chux: In your example, `command` should not have more than 12 characters, which makes the `sprintf` version a buffer overrun *in addition* to the possibility of formatting the disk. So it's not trading one set of problems for another; it's merely removing some set of problems. Not *all* problems; just some of them. If you have two tools that do the same job, but one has problems that are a strict subset of the other, then you should use the one with the smaller set of problems. I never claimed that this was the empty set.

Comment: @NicolBolas The trick is that `snprintf()` forms a disjoint set of issues, not certainly a _strict subset_ of `sprintf()` problems as the later is UB, which can include desirable outcomes versus an undesirable truncated string.  IAC, C obliges good coding around both `sprintf()/snprintf()` and weak coding will break either approach.  It is this _other_ needed code that helps distinguish if indeed `snprintf()` formed a superior solution or just masked them.  IMO, too often implementations, of both approaches, are simplistic and lack proper error handling -  rendering both weak.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use either of these.  Use `std::stringstream` and so on.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << x;
ss.str();  // Access the std::string
```

Either way, it's quite unlikely that converting to string will be a significant part of your application's execution time.

Comment: It's not me, but  I guess the down vote might be because this answer doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: `stringstream` is extremely slow, this might be significant part in SOME applications (in HFT trading for example), also it doesn't allow to convert to existent `char*` buffer.

Comment: @javapowered: Presumably HFT algorithms don't spend a great deal of their time constructing human-readable strings?

Answer (score 14):

They're both efficient. It's probably much more relevant to note that `itoa()` is not part of the C++ standard, and as such is not available in many common runtimes. (In particular, it's not part of `libstdc++`, so it's not available on Mac OS X or Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

From a pure algorithm viewpoint one can argue that `itoa` would be faster since `sprintf` has the additional cost of parsing the format descriptor string. However without benchmarking the cost of the two functions in an implementation, with a non-trivial work load, one cannot be sure.

Also this isn't apples to apples comparison since both functions aren't equivalent. `sprintf` can do much more formatting than `itoa` does, apart from the fact that the former is a standard function while the latter isn't.

**Aside:** If you can use C++11 you can use `to_string` which returns you an `std::string`. If you want representations other than decimal you may do this:

```
int i = 1234;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << i;       // hexadecimal
ss << std::oct << i;       // octal
ss << std::dec << i;       // decimal

std::bitset<sizeof(int) * std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits> b(i);
ss << b;                   // binary

std::string str = ss.str();
```